# Problem with "docker login registry.domain.com"

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers, registry, gitlab-ci

I have installed Gitlab via Docker and want to use registry.
I've configured everything, When i try to login i see:

```sh
root@book:/srv/gitlab/logs/nginx# docker login 172.50.0.10:5050
Username: 1
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://172.50.0.10:5050/v2/: error parsing HTTP 404 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n    <head>\n        <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">\n\n        <title>Not Found</title>\n\n        <!-- Fonts -->\n        <link rel=\"dns-prefetch\" href=\"//fonts.gstatic.com\">\n        <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n\n        <!-- Styles -->\n        <style>\n            html, body {\n                background-color: #fff;\n                color: #636b6f;\n                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;\n                font-weight: 100;\n                height: 100vh;\n                margin: 0;\n            }\n\n            .full-height {\n                height: 100vh;\n            }\n\n            .flex-center {\n                align-items: center;\n                display: flex;\n                justify-content: center;\n            }\n\n            .position-ref {\n                position: relative;\n            }\n\n            .code {\n                border-right: 2px solid;\n                font-size: 26px;\n                padding: 0 15px 0 15px;\n                text-align: center;\n            }\n\n            .message {\n                font-size: 18px;\n                text-align: center;\n            }\n        </style>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <div class=\"flex-center position-ref full-height\">\n            <div class=\"code\">\n                404            </div>\n\n            <div class=\"message\" style=\"padding: 10px;\">\n                Not Found            </div>\n        </div>\n    </body>\n</html>\n"
```

If I try to use domain instead of IP I get:

```sh
root@book:/srv/gitlab/logs/nginx# docker login gitlab.example.com:5050
Username: test
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://gitlab.example.com:5050/v2/: dial tcp 125.11.111.14:5050: connect: connection refused
```

I understand that I must use container's IP address but I've got 404 :(

Logs:

```sh
==> /var/log/gitlab/registry/current <==
2020-07-18_15:54:07.97885 time="2020-07-18T15:54:07.978770522Z" level=warning msg="error authorizing context: authorization token required" go.version=go1.13.9 http.request.host="172.50.0.10:5050" http.request.id=bb60f524-e8f6-4eeb-acc8-71cbc3caf23c http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr=172.50.0.1 http.request.uri="/v2/" http.request.useragent="docker/19.03.12 go/go1.13.10 git-commit/48a66213fe kernel/4.15.0-111-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.12 \(linux\))" 
2020-07-18_15:54:07.97890 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2020:15:54:07 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "" "docker/19.03.12 go/go1.13.10 git-commit/48a66213fe kernel/4.15.0-111-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.12 \\(linux\\))"

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_registry_access.log <==
172.50.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2020:15:54:07 +0000] "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" 401 87 "" "docker/19.03.12 go/go1.13.10 git-commit/48a66213fe kernel/4.15.0-111-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.12 \x5C(linux\x5C))" -
```

SOLVED: I was running container with ports 444:443, I've changed it to 444:444
And it works

Comment: Can you explain more about how you installed GitLab? The error looks like nginx is not configured to serve the registry at the IP address. Your domain appears to resolve to a public address. Please illustrate more about the setup.

Comment: @AndyShinn Installed via Docker, I understand that registry installed automatically with gitlab, if we trust the official docs.

Comment: Which install docs? They have different docs for different platforms.

Comment: @AndyShinn https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html
Omnibus GitLab installations (Docker Image)